# How to get to the database mariadb To access?

Tags: mariadb

When I log in to mariadb, I do not have access to a database named mysql.

I get the following error:
MariaDB [(none)]> use mysql
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mysql'

Comment: The `root` user can use the `GRANT` command to give `user@localhost` permission to access `mysql.*`.'

Comment: More importantly, is the database yours? and it seems like you're using empty username..

Comment: I enter with the root user, with the command mysql -u root . When I log in and try to select the mysql database with command USE mysql, it does not give me access

Comment: If that's the exact error message you're getting, you're not actually using `root`. If you are, then the error message would be like this `ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'mysql'`.